# Can't connect to server after Arch Linux upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade

I get no errors when starting nginx, sshd, vsftp, etc.  But access from other computers time out. All apps seem to be listening on the correct ports.  All are on local address 0.0.0.0 and Foreign Address 0.0.0.0:* when running netstat -ltnp.

All worked fine prior to the upgrade and jounralctl -xe shows no errors with the respective packages.

So something is preventing them from communicating on the dedicated IP address of the server.

Any ideas would be helpful as our web server, ssh server and ftp server are not accessible from the outside world.

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Is there a firewall running on your server? If yes, have you checked for unexpected changes in its configuration? Also, a kind of dumb question: have you checked that the current IP address of the server is still the intended one?

Answer (score 0):

As user @fra-san pointed, check the following:
1) Current IP address is the one expected to be up and running
2) Check if firewall service is up, it could be one of firewalld, ufw, or iptables depending on what Arch Linux is based on.

Try connecting with a:

```
telnet localhost <desired-port-to-check>
```

Sometimes it happens that when deploying a new server, one stops the FW but, doesn't disables the FW entirely on reboot. FW could have been stopped but enabled on boot.

Comment: The address of the server is fixed and I can ping it from outside. I'll check the firewall.

Comment: Yes, I thought an upgrade would leave ufw as is.  But I needed to enter all new allows.